# OneSignal - Send Notification to all devices of some users

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I'm developing an app/website where the user has to be logged in, so I can identify them via email. In the app the user can register for push-notifications about different topics. I'm filtering the target-users via OneSignal's tag feature.

Since a user can be logged in with one account on multiple devices, the notifications should be sent to all of the user's devices.

Is there any way to do this?

Update:
I found some information on the following link:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/internal-database-crm

But I would honestly prefer a solution, which doesn't require storing all the playerIds in my database.